# How can I get Spring to run my custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer _after_ the injectors run

Tags: java, spring

I have defined a custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which makes a REST call to get the properties that are used to resolve the placeholders.

However the REST call URL is injected by Spring. And apparently this injection is called *after* the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is done. This is causing an exception, since the URL is null at the time the PlaceholderConfigurer needs it.

I need the chicken to come before the egg. Is there any way to get the injectors to run *before* the PlaceholderConfigurer? If not, is there some way for the PlaceholderConfigurer to get a sneak preview of the coming injections?

Answer (score 1):

We run a similar configuration, in our case we have the database credentials stored in a local config file, all other properties are stored in the database.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:app.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="$["/>
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="]"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="com.acme.util.DatabasePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

In our case, the DatabasePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer needs to access a Spring Bean (the DataSource), so we use the BeanFactory in the override 'mergeProperties()' method to retrieve that DataSource. In your case, the configuration is a lot simpler, since you need a simple URL configuration value.

The example below might do the trick: (please notice that the two configurers use a different prefix/suffix: $[] instead of ${})

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="com.acme.util.RESTPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="url" value="$[config.url]"/>
</bean>
```